# Proof that universal class is a proper class?

Tags: analysis, set-theory, alternative-set-theories

I've been trying to work out this proof, but I think there's something I'm missing out because with the deductions I made, it much looks like the universal class is a set... (help).

So in my class we're using Von Neumann-Bernays-Gödel's axiomatic set theory (NBG), which is also presented in Dugundji's "Topology" (1966). The definitions, propositions and axioms I have to work until now to demonstrate the stated are the following:

- **Definition** $\left( A \subset B \right) \iff \left( \forall x : x \in A \implies x \in B \right)$
- **Definition** $\left( A = B \right) \iff \left( A \subset B \right) \wedge \left( B \subset A \right)$
- **Definition (of a Set)** The class $x$ is a set only if there exists a class $A$ such as $x \in A$.
- **Proposition** For all class $x$, $x=x$.
- **Proposition** $\left( x \in A \right) \wedge \left( A = B \right) \implies \left( x \in B \right)$
- **Axiom I (of Individuality)** $\left(x \in A\right) \wedge \left(x = y\right) \implies y \in A$
- **Axiom II (of Class Formation)** $\left( x \in A \right) \iff \left( x \,\,\text{is a set} \right) \wedge p(x)$.

And the **universal class** was defined as $U := \{ x : \left( x \,\,\text{is a set} \right) \wedge \left( x = x \right) \}$. Also, a **proper class** was defined as every class that is not a set.

The exercise is "Prove that the universal class $U$ is a proper class".

So the way I'm approaching the demonstration goes like this:

> We want to prove that the universal class $U$ is a proper class $\iff$ we want to prove that the universal class $U$ is not a set.

> By contradiction, let's assume $U$ is a set. In general, $U$ is still a class so it satisfies $U = U$. Then, by the definition of $U$ it follows that $U \in U$ (because it is a set and it is equal to itself).

...And that's everything I have! I haven't been able to find any contradictions to this procedure. Also, I haven't come up with any other ideas to approach the exercise.

I would really appreciate your help!

P.S. I tagged this with "analysis" because it's the course I'm learning this topic in!

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. I suspect a from-the-axioms proof will be quite long. I've not had much practice in NBG, but in e.g. ZF set theory you first prove [Cantor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem), then note $\mathcal{P}(U)\subseteq U$.

Comment: Shouldn't [Russel's Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_paradox) work?

Comment: @J.G. Thanks! Yes, I suspect that the proof should be either too "long" or "short" because of the tools we have. And what you state is quiet interesting! I made the demonstration using Cantor's theorem and indeed leads to a contradiction (just like link you attached explains) so we can conclude the set of all sets does not exists and it could only be a proper class. I'm just getting familiar with all these topics, and I have a question (it might sound silly...): is Cantor's theorem valid for any set theory? Because you mentioned ZF, but I thought that theory didn't use the concept of "class".

Comment: @Karl I think it does! Based on the answer by Robert Murray on this post. I also thought of it, but didn't know how to develop the idea. How would you demonstrate this using it? (:

Comment: Well, in ZF we don't so much prove the class of sets satisfying a unary predicate $\phi$ isn't a set as prove there is no set of sets satisfying $\phi$. In NBG, you can restate proofs of the first kind to instead be of the second.

Comment: @Karl That would use specification.

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably need Axiom of Sifting, which states that if $A$ is a set and $\mathscr A$ is a class, then $A\cap \mathscr A$ is a set. This axiom is stated below axiom of class formation but before the problem "8.10 The class of all sets is not a set" in the book. It has a similar function of Axiom of Comprehension in ZFC.

If this is allowed, then the proof goes as follows: assume $\mathscr U$ is a set, then the Russell class $\mathscr R$, defined through Axiom II as $$x\in\mathscr R\iff x\text{ is a set}\;\wedge\;\neg (x\in x)$$ is set. Indeed, Axiom of Sifting applied to $\mathscr R = \mathscr U\cap \mathscr R$ gives this result.

Assume $\mathscr R\in\mathscr R$. Then, by definition, $\mathscr R\notin \mathscr R$, contradiction.

Assume $\mathscr R\notin \mathscr R$. Since $\mathscr R$ (on LHS) is a set, and $\mathscr R$ (on RHS) contains all sets $x$ with $x\notin x$, $\mathscr R\in \mathscr R$. This is again a contradiction.

---

Without sifting, it is consistent with Axioms I and II to have the set of all set being a set. In fact, consider the following universe $U=\{\circ,\bullet\}$, where we define the binary relation $\in$ as follows:

| $\in$ | $\circ$ | $\bullet$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $\circ$ | $\circ\notin\circ$ | $\circ\notin\bullet$ |
| $\bullet$ | $\bullet\notin\circ$ | $\bullet\in\bullet$ |

Then, $\circ$ is a proper class, since no classes contains it. On the other hand, $\bullet$ is a set, which is coincidentally the set of all sets. We check that Axiom II holds for this universe:

Let $p(x)$ be a proposition with free variable $x$.

Case 1: $p(\bullet)$ holds. Then, $x\in \bullet\iff x\text{ is a set}\wedge p(x)$. So $p$ forms the class $\bullet$.

Case 2: $p(\bullet)$ does not hold. Then, $x\in \circ\iff x\text{ is a set}\wedge p(x)$. So $p$ forms the class $\circ$.

As you can see, $(U,\in)$ provides an example of axioms I and II. Therefore, it is not possible to exclude the set of all set from these axioms alone. Note $U$ clearly does not satisfy sifting:  $\circ\cap\bullet=\circ$ is not a set.